# How Store Web Crawling in Database with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, laravel, dom, web-crawler, goutte

I'have got web crawling from other website and i'have got data what i need. Now i want to store it in my own database. How to do it?

here what the data i'have got
[data from other website i'have got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a6ir.jpg)

```
    [{"judul":"Potensi Ekonomi Kota Padang","no katalog":"9102059.1371","no publikasi":"13710.1720","isbn":"978-602-0919-95-9","rilis":"2017-12-29","size":"2.72 MB ","abstrak":"Publikasi Potensi Ekonomi Kota Padang 2016 ini ditujukan untuk memperoleh gambaran dan informasi kategori ekonomi potensi dan unggulan di Kota Padang. Informasi ini sangat bermanfaat bagi pemerintah dalam mengevaluasi program-program terkait pengembangan potensi ekonomi yang sudah dilakukan selama ini.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9ZDE4ZjhlYWUxNzlhMGZlMDUzM2RmY2I2","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=ZDE4ZjhlYWUxNzlhMGZlMDUzM2RmY2I2&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzEyLzI5L2QxOGY4ZWFlMTc5YTBmZTA1MzNkZmNiNi9wb3RlbnNpLWVrb25vbWkta290YS1wYWRhbmcuaHRtbA%3D%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Statistik Kesejahteraan Rakyat Kota Padang 2017","no katalog":"4101002","no publikasi":"13710.1719","isbn":"978-602-0919-93-5","rilis":"2017-12-29","size":"7.24 MB ","abstrak":"Data dan informasi diperlukan dalam rangka mendukung proses perencanaan, implementasi dan evaluasi hasil pembangunan agar dapat berjalan dengan baik. Data mengenai keadaan sosial ekonomi dibutuhkan untuk memberikan gambaran pencapaian pembangunan dan juga dapat digunakan oleh para pengambil kebijakan untuk mengevaluasi program-program pembangunan. Data yang terkait dengan kebutuhan hidup masyarakat seperti sandang, pangan, papan, pendidikan, kesehatan, keamanan, dan kesempatan kerja diperlukan untuk mengetahui seberapa jauh pencapaian hasil-hasil pembangunan menjangkau seluruh lapisan masyarakat. Survei Sosial Ekonomi Nasional (Susenas) dirancang untuk menghasilkan data sosial ekonomi penduduk di sektor pendidikan, kesehatan, perumahan, kriminalitas, sosial-budaya, perjalanan wisata, dan perlindungan sosial. Tahun 2017, pengumpulan data Susenas dilaksanakan dua kali dalam setahun yaitu pada bulan Maret dan bulan September. Publikasi Statistik Kesejahteraan Rakyat tahun 2017 merupakan hasil pengumpulan data melalui kuesioner Kor Susenas Maret 2017 (Daftar VSEN2017.K) yang dilaksanakan di seluruh wilayah Indonesia. Publikasi ini disajikan dalam bentuk angka persentase sehingga pengguna data dapat mengetahui perbedaan tingkat kesejahteraan antar wilayah. Sejumlah data dibedakan pula Menurut jenis kelamin untuk memenuhi kebutuhan analisis kesenjangan gender. Dengan terbitnya buku ini, diharapkan kebutuhan data statistik kesejahteraan rakyat sebagian besar sudah dapat dipenuhi. Kepada semua pihak yang telah ikut berpartisipasi dalam mengusahakan terwujudnya publikasi ini, diucapkan terima kasih.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9Y2U3NGJkN2MzNTI4YjJjMzdlYjNiNmE2","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=Y2U3NGJkN2MzNTI4YjJjMzdlYjNiNmE2&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzEyLzI5L2NlNzRiZDdjMzUyOGIyYzM3ZWIzYjZhNi9zdGF0aXN0aWsta2VzZWphaHRlcmFhbi1yYWt5YXQta290YS1wYWRhbmctMjAxNy5odG1s&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Indikator Kesejahteraan Rakyat Kota Padang 2016","no katalog":"4102004.1371","no publikasi":"13710.1718","isbn":"978-602-0919-94-2","rilis":"2017-11-24","size":"5 MB ","abstrak":"Publikasi ini merupakan publikasi yang bersumber dari hasil pengumpulan data Survei Sosial Ekonomi Nasional tahun 2016 yang telah dilakukan oleh Badan Pusat Statistik Kota Padang. Selain itu sumber tambahan yang dimuat dalam publikasi ini berasal dari hasil Sensus Penduduk Kota Padang Tahun 2010 dan publikasi Padang Dalam Angka Tahun 2016. Keterangan yang dikumpulkan menyangkut berbagai aspek kehidupan sosial ekonomi penduduk, antara lain mengenai keadaan demografi, kesehatan, pendidikan, angkatan kerja, fertilitas dan keluarga berencana, dan perumahan","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9NGY2MWFhZjM4Y2U2MzQyYWU3ZWYwYzdm","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=NGY2MWFhZjM4Y2U2MzQyYWU3ZWYwYzdm&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzExLzI0LzRmNjFhYWYzOGNlNjM0MmFlN2VmMGM3Zi9pbmRpa2F0b3Ita2VzZWphaHRlcmFhbi1yYWt5YXQta290YS1wYWRhbmctMjAxNi5odG1s&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},{"judul":"Indikator Ekonomi Kota Padang 2016","no katalog":"9201001.1371","no publikasi":"13710.1716","isbn":"978-602-0919-91-1","rilis":"2017-11-06","size":"6 MB ","abstrak":"Buku \u201c Indikator Ekonomi Kota Padang Tahun 2016 \u201c merupakan jenis publikasi yang secara rutin disiapkan oleh Badan Pusat Statistik Kota Padang. Buku ini memuat data tentang perkembangan harga dan indeks konsumen, produksi hasil pertanian, industri pengolahan, listrik dan air minum, perdagangan, hotel dan restoran, pengangkutan dan komunikasi, bank dan lembaga keuangan lainnya, keuangan daerah serta pendapatan regional. Diharapkan data yang disajikan ini akan bermanfaat bagi konsumen data, terutama dalam menyusun perencanaan, mengevaluasi hasil pembangunan ekonomi Kota Padang dimasa datang","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9ZmQ5YTNhZTQwMDJlOGM0MjY3YzExYTJk","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=ZmQ5YTNhZTQwMDJlOGM0MjY3YzExYTJk&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzExLzA2L2ZkOWEzYWU0MDAyZThjNDI2N2MxMWEyZC9pbmRpa2F0b3ItZWtvbm9taS1rb3RhLXBhZGFuZy0yMDE2Lmh0bWw%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Statistik Kesejahteraan Rakyat Kota Padang 2016","no katalog":"4101002","no publikasi":"13710.1717","isbn":"978-602-0919-69-0","rilis":"2017-11-01","size":"3 MB ","abstrak":"Publikasi Statistik Kesejahteraan Rakyat tahun 2016 merupakan hasil pengumpulan data melalui kuesioner Kor Susenas Maret 2016 yang dilaksanakan di seluruh wilayah Indonesia. Publikasi ini disajikan dalam bentuk angka persentase sehingga pengguna data dapat mengetahui perbedaan tingkat kesejahteraan antar wilayah. Dengan terbitnya buku ini diharapkan kebutuhan data statistik kesejahteraan rakyat sebagian besar sudah dapat dipenuhi.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9NGNmZTI4ZDIxNzk1NmMwMmM0NTc0MmU0","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=NGNmZTI4ZDIxNzk1NmMwMmM0NTc0MmU0&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzExLzAxLzRjZmUyOGQyMTc5NTZjMDJjNDU3NDJlNC9zdGF0aXN0aWsta2VzZWphaHRlcmFhbi1yYWt5YXQta290YS1wYWRhbmctMjAxNi5odG1s&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},{"judul":"Statistik Daerah Kota Padang 2017","no katalog":"1101002.1371","no publikasi":"13710.1715","isbn":"978-602-0919-90-4","rilis":"2017-10-26","size":"8 MB ","abstrak":"Publikasi ini dimaksudkan untuk memotret serta menyajikan indikator-indikator penting yang menggambarkan tentang kondisi daerah dalam bentuk tampilan uraian deskriptif sederhana. Publikasi Statistik Daerah Kota Padang Tahun 2017 ini bertujuan untuk memberikan informasi secara cepat dan tepat kepada pemerintah daerah dan masyarakat yang dapat digunakan sebagai dasar perencanaan, monitoring dan evaluasi mengenai perkembangan pembangunan di berbagai sektor serta membantu para pengguna data lainnya dalam memahami kondisi umum daerahnya.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9MWNmNzBmNThmYTcwY2IyNmQzMzM1YjVh","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=MWNmNzBmNThmYTcwY2IyNmQzMzM1YjVh&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzEwLzI2LzFjZjcwZjU4ZmE3MGNiMjZkMzMzNWI1YS9zdGF0aXN0aWstZGFlcmFoLWtvdGEtcGFkYW5nLTIwMTcuaHRtbA%3D%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Kecamatan Kuranji Dalam Angka 2017","no katalog":"1102001.1371090","no publikasi":"13710.1710","isbn":"978-602-0919-85-0","rilis":"2017-09-20","size":"2 MB ","abstrak":"Kecamatan Kuranji Dalam Angka 2017 merupakan publikasi yang diterbitkan setiap tahun oleh Koordinator Statistik Kecamatan Kuranji BPS Kota Padang guna memenuhi kebutuhan pemakai data. Publikasi ini menyajikan beraneka jenis data dari berbagai sektor sebagai gambaran umum keadaan di Kecamatan Kuranji. Publikasi ini merupakan lanjutan dari publikasi tahun sebelumnya yang secara bertahap telah diusahakan untuk disempurnakan, baik kualitas maupun kuantitasnya. Sebagian besar, tabel-tabelnya menyajikan data tahun 2016, namun apabila data tahun terakhir belum tersedia, maka data yang disajikan adalah data tahun sebelumnya.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9MjY1ZTJiNjkxYzBlZmUzZWU1ZjU0MzEz","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=MjY1ZTJiNjkxYzBlZmUzZWU1ZjU0MzEz&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzA5LzIwLzI2NWUyYjY5MWMwZWZlM2VlNWY1NDMxMy9rZWNhbWF0YW4ta3VyYW5qaS1kYWxhbS1hbmdrYS0yMDE3Lmh0bWw%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},{"judul":"Kecamatan Koto Tangah Dalam Angka 2017","no katalog":"1102001.1371110","no publikasi":"13710.1711","isbn":"978-602-0919-87-4","rilis":"2017-09-19","size":"5.7 MB ","abstrak":"Kecamatan Koto Tangah Dalam Angka 2017 merupakan publikasi yang diterbitkan setiap tahun oleh Koordinator Statistik Kecamatan Koto Tangah BPS Kota Padang guna memenuhi kebutuhan pemakai data. Publikasi ini menyajikan beraneka jenis data dari berbagai sektor sebagai gambaran umum keadaan di Kecamatan Koto Tangah. Publikasi ini merupakan lanjutan dari publikasi tahun sebelumnya yang secara bertahap telah diusahakan untuk disempurnakan, baik kualitas maupun kuantitasnya. Sebagian besar, tabel-tabelnya menyajikan data tahun 2016, namun apabila data tahun terakhir belum tersedia, maka data yang disajikan adalah data tahun sebelumnya.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9ZmMwODEwMWJlOTI4ZDYzYWRmYmUwM2Fk","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=ZmMwODEwMWJlOTI4ZDYzYWRmYmUwM2Fk&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzA5LzE5L2ZjMDgxMDFiZTkyOGQ2M2FkZmJlMDNhZC9rZWNhbWF0YW4ta290by10YW5nYWgtZGFsYW0tYW5na2EtMjAxNy5odG1s&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Kecamatan Padang Timur Dalam Angka 2017","no katalog":"1102001.1371050","no publikasi":"13710.1714","isbn":"978-602-0919-81-2","rilis":"2017-09-19","size":"4 MB ","abstrak":"Kecamatan Padang Timur Dalam Angka 2017 merupakan publikasi yang diterbitkan setiap tahun oleh Koordinator Statistik Kecamatan Padang Timur BPS Kota Padang guna memenuhi kebutuhan pemakai data. Publikasi ini menyajikan beraneka jenis data dari berbagai sektor sebagai gambaran umum keadaan di Kecamatan Padang Timur. Publikasi ini merupakan lanjutan dari publikasi tahun sebelumnya yang secara bertahap telah diusahakan untuk disempurnakan, baik kualitas maupun kuantitasnya. Sebagian besar, tabel-tabelnya menyajikan data tahun 2016, namun apabila data tahun terakhir belum tersedia, maka data yang disajikan adalah data tahun sebelumnya.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9ZTE2MjZmOWRjM2Q4ZDg1MWRiNjFkOThh","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=ZTE2MjZmOWRjM2Q4ZDg1MWRiNjFkOThh&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzA5LzE5L2UxNjI2ZjlkYzNkOGQ4NTFkYjYxZDk4YS9rZWNhbWF0YW4tcGFkYW5nLXRpbXVyLWRhbGFtLWFuZ2thLTIwMTcuaHRtbA%3D%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"},
{"judul":"Kecamatan Bungus Teluk Kabung Dalam Angka 2017","no katalog":"1102001.1371010","no publikasi":"13710.1708","isbn":"978-602-0919-77-5","rilis":"2017-09-19","size":"4 MB ","abstrak":"Kecamatan Bungus Teluk Kabung Dalam Angka 2017 merupakan publikasi yang diterbitkan setiap tahun oleh Koordinator Statistik Kecamatan Bungus Teluk Kabung BPS Kota Padang guna memenuhi kebutuhan pemakai data. Publikasi ini menyajikan beraneka jenis data dari berbagai sektor sebagai gambaran umum keadaan di Kecamatan Bungus Teluk Kabung. Publikasi ini merupakan lanjutan dari publikasi tahun sebelumnya yang secara bertahap telah diusahakan untuk disempurnakan, baik kualitas maupun kuantitasnya. Sebagian besar, tabel-tabelnya menyajikan data tahun 2016, namun apabila data tahun terakhir belum tersedia, maka data yang disajikan adalah data tahun sebelumnya.","image":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/getImageCover.html?url=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCMjaHR0cHM6Ly9wb3J0YWxwdWJsaWthc2kuYnBzLmdvLmlkL2FwaS9nZXRLb3Zlci5waHA%2Fc2VsZWN0b3I9ZDZlMTk3NTIxMzJkNGE2YWRlYTNlM2Zk","download":"https:\/\/padangkota.bps.go.id\/publication\/download.html?nrbvfeve=ZDZlMTk3NTIxMzJkNGE2YWRlYTNlM2Zk&xzmn=aHR0cHM6Ly9wYWRhbmdrb3RhLmJwcy5nby5pZC9wdWJsaWNhdGlvbi8yMDE3LzA5LzE5L2Q2ZTE5NzUyMTMyZDRhNmFkZWEzZTNmZC9rZWNhbWF0YW4tYnVuZ3VzLXRlbHVrLWthYnVuZy1kYWxhbS1hbmdrYS0yMDE3Lmh0bWw%3D&twoadfnoarfeauf=MjAxOC0wNS0xMCAwNzoyNTozMQ%3D%3D"}]
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please make some attempts and share your code if you're unable to get it to work. This type of question will illicit long back-and-forth conversations, which is a poor fit for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse it like this,

```
$parsed_data = json_decode($your_data);
```

Here you will get PHP array of data you can use laravel bulk insertion method

```
YourModel::insert($parsed_data);
```

Make sure your have correct mapping between table columns and array keys.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems it's in JSON formate. Use any server side languages like PHP or Node.js to parse the data. After parsing the data you can push to your database, like each record as a row in the table in your database. You have to create columns based on your data.

Comment: how to parse the data with php? i use laravel and the table is already exist